# D3 bisector function not working properly

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following set of data:

```
const data = [
  {
    value: 5.9,
    date: '2019-12-16T10:02:06.000Z',
  },
  {
    value: 5.8,
    date: '2019-12-04T12:06:20.000Z',
  },
  {
    value: 5.5,
    date: '2019-11-23T13:45:37.000Z',
  },
  {
    value: 4.1,
    date: '2019-11-13T10:05:02.000Z',
  },
  {
    value: 4.1,
    date: '2019-11-01T12:50:19.000Z',
  },
  {
    value: 4.3,
    date: '2019-10-22T10:10:21.000Z',
  },
  {
    value: 4.3,
    date: '2019-10-08T21:36:06.000Z',
  },
  {
    value: 4.3,
    date: '2019-09-28T18:12:12.000Z',
  },
  {
    value: 4.2,
    date: '2019-09-18T15:01:38.000Z',
  },
  {
    value: 4.1,
    date: '2019-09-08T09:38:23.000Z',
  },
  {
    value: 4,
    date: '2019-08-29T02:38:01.000Z',
  },
  {
    value: 4,
    date: '2019-08-18T22:25:18.000Z',
  },
  {
    value: 4,
    date: '2019-08-12T12:30:50.000Z',
  },
  {
    value: 4,
    date: '2019-08-08T18:26:10.000Z',
  },
  {
    value: 4,
    date: '2019-07-28T17:53:02.000Z',
  },
  {
    value: 4,
    date: '2019-07-18T17:37:24.000Z',
  },
  {
    value: 4.1,
    date: '2019-07-08T11:44:27.000Z',
  },
  {
    value: 4,
    date: '2019-06-27T06:56:31.000Z',
  },
  {
    value: 4.1,
    date: '2019-06-16T00:25:23.000Z',
  },
  {
    value: 3.9,
    date: '2019-06-05T21:04:26.000Z',
  },
]
```

I am using the following bisector function:

`import { bisector } from 'd3-array'`

`const bisectDate = bisector(d => new Date(d.date)).left`

I am using this in a tooltip function where the bisecting date is retrieved from the chart `x0`, so is within the domain of the date scale.

`const index = bisectDate(data, x0)`

When I try to get the index of a particular date with that function, all dates before Aug 29 yield an index of 0, and all dates after and including Aug 29th yield an index of 20.

What's interesting is when I use the following data, the function works perfectly. The proper index is returned for a given date:

```
const data2 = [
  {
    value: 4.1,
    date: new Date(2018, 9, 1),
  },
  {
    value: 4.3,
    date: new Date(2018, 10, 1),
  },
  {
    value: 4.3,
    date: new Date(2018, 11, 1),
  },
  {
    value: 4.3,
    date: new Date(2018, 12, 1),
  },
  {
    value: 4.2,
    date: new Date(2019, 1, 1),
  },
  {
    value: 4.1,
    date: new Date(2019, 2, 1),
  },
  {
    value: 4,
    date: new Date(2019, 3, 1),
  },
  {
    value: 4,
    date: new Date(2019, 4, 1),
  },
  {
    value: 4,
    date: new Date(2019, 5, 1),
  },
  {
    value: 4,
    date: new Date(2019, 6, 1),
  },
  {
    value: 4,
    date: new Date(2019, 7, 1),
  },
  {
    value: 4,
    date: new Date(2019, 8, 1),
  },
  {
    value: 4.1,
    date: new Date(2019, 9, 1),
  },
  {
    value: 4,
    date: new Date(2019, 10, 1),
  },
  {
    value: 4.1,
    date: new Date(2019, 11, 1),
  },
  {
    value: 3.9,
    date: new Date(2019, 12, 1),
  },
]
```

I thought maybe the only difference was the Date parsing so I changed my original data dates to a format like: `date: new Date(2019, 6, 8)` Seeing that my data dates are significant at least down to the day. With this format change I still run into the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

After writing all this up I realized the difference with the array of data that worked was the fact that the array was sorted by the date in ascending order. The actual data array I was using was sorted by date in descending order. This was rendering fine in d3 but the bisector function does not work in date descending. Going back now, I couldn't find much about this in the docs. I hope this saves someone some time.

Comment: You might want to spice up your answer with some references and code to make it a good helpful post. E.g., the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#bisector) have you covered pretty clearly: *"Use a comparator rather than an accessor if you want values to be **sorted in an order different than natural order, such as in descending rather than ascending order**."*

Comment: @altocumulus I was just looking to help. No code or references needed. I read the same docs that you did but it didn't make it clear to me that in order for the bisector function to work, the array needs to be sorted in ascending order. E.g. "if you want values to be sorted..." At the time, I didn't think sorting had anything to do with my problem... so this wording in the docs was unhelpful.

Comment: Just spent like 4 hours playing with date formats when this was the issue all along :,(

Comment: It definitely took me too long to find this. But it definitely saved me time!!